# What is a word for a person, being copied?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am working on a programming problem and I need to name the roles, that a user can take. I have `copiers` and I need to think of a good name for the person, that is being copied by the `copiers`. A first choice would be a `leader`. The problem is that this name has already been taken, as I also have `followers`, who follow `leaders`. Other options I thought of are:

- `copy_leader`
- `originator`

Yet, I would like a better word for this.

Comment: Try author or content generator if you don't like originator.

Comment: I would suggest "clonee".

Comment: I think you could use "sources."

Comment: The 'Original' ?

Comment: So far all are close, but not yet there. Currently, I find `originator` most suitable.

Comment: I would use Model.

Comment: *Disciples* (= followers).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the choosing of names for computer things is specifically off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: I vote with tchrist… and even if it wasn't off topic, the OQ has had several obviously acceptable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider ***master***. The definition (3) below implies one who creates (rather than copies) and definition (6) below implies *originality* (though it applies to *what is done/created* rather than *who does it*).

ODO:

> **[master](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/master)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **3** A skilled practitioner of a particular art or activity.
>
> ‘It was indeed the activity of the geniuses, of the masters of their craft, that made the rules.’
>
> **6** An original movie, recording, or document from which copies can be made.
>   [as modifier] ‘the master tape’
>
> ‘The videos all look fairly good, as if derived from the original
>   masters.’